# creating time specific threads

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I have written a sample program to implement array of threads.There are two thread functions. Is there any way to **define a fixed value of time** (in seconds) after which all the threads will automatically stop?

Sample program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>


void * threadFunc1(void * arg)
{

    int id = *((int *) arg);
    printf("Inside threadfunc2 for thread %d\n",id)
    while(1);
}

void * threadFunc2(void * arg)
{
    int i= *((int *)arg);
    printf("Inside threadfunc2 for thread %d\n",i)
    while(1);
}

int main(void)
{

    pthread_t thread[10];

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {

        pthread_create(&thread[i],NULL,threadFunc1,(void*)&i ); 
        pthread_create(&thread[i],NULL,threadFunc,(void*)&i );
    }

    for (i=0;i<total;i++)
    {
          pthread_join(thread[i],NULL);
      }
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: You know about mutexes? You can defined a common variable to measure time, but to access it correctly you need to synchronize the threads.

Comment: The code does not even compile, why do you post things like that? Further, why is it necessary to create an array of threads at all? Your question is completely unrelated to that. Lastly, you are creating more threads than you join, which is another issue.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of waiting for the threads with `pthread_join` you could put your `main` thread to sleep, e.g with `nanosleep`. If you then quit your `main` without joining, your whole process will be killed.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not.  Threads do not 'automatically stop'